# Php email process form triggers download

Tags: php

Php email process form triggers download. I wrote this code in college and have used it for multiple sites and it works great, but on this server for some reason it triggers a download of the entire php page. Anyone have any ideas why? I have checked the code over a 1000 times and it is the same.

Comment: Is server not running Apache ?

Comment: This is likely an error of the web server config more than with your code. PHP is not configured as CGI module nor as Plugin to the web server.

Comment: In a file, just write `<?php phpinfo();` & then try accessing that page.If this works fine, It means php/apache is working fine & then we need to check your code.

Comment: Thanks guys. It is the clients hosting package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the web-server offers a .php file for download then he is not configured properly to parse the script. To make sure that this is the case, create a info.php with this content:

```
<?php 
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

If it offers you that file for download as well, make sure that you have installed/enabled your desired php parser (e.g. PHP5-FPM), to get it working.